# Vgo build triggers "unknown directive: go"?

Tags: go, go-packages

Any vgo command shows the same error with parsing go.mod file.
`unknown directive: go`

Here is my go.mod file:

```
module github.com/SvitlanaShepitsena/surf

go 1.13

require (
    github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery v1.5.0
    github.com/headzoo/surf v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/headzoo/ut v0.0.0-20181013193318-a13b5a7a02ca // indirect
    gopkg.in/headzoo/surf.v1 v1.0.0
)
```

I am using  `go1.13beta1` version.

Comment: What do you mean by "Any vgo command"? If you're using `go1.13beta1`, what are you doing with `vgo`?

Comment: Thank you, Jim. I meant:
`vgo build` , `vgo get` it parsed my go.mod and gives this error. 

I switched to 1.12 as I cannot debug with delve in `go1.13beta1`, but the error is still the same. Any suggestion - and I am not golang pro, so if you can explain a bit your answers - I would appreciate it :-). 

Currently switched to deb - working perfectly... I may stay here despite all the suggestions from pro. 

Thank you

Comment: `vgo` was an proof of concept before module support was added to go. Don’t use it any more.

Comment: so just go get is the best option?

Comment: Yes, the `go` command supports modules in 1.12 and 1.13 (with some support in older versions too). Read https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules for a quick reference to how to use modules.

Comment: ok, thank you! Just fell in love with dep - until I get a serious problem will stick with it.